# How to enable trackpad right button in GNOME, Debian 10 Buster

Tags: debian, gnome, touchpad

I just installed Debian 10.0 Buster, and the right mouse button on my trackpad didn't work or was disabled.  The default desktop is GNOME 3.30.2.

Comment: Please post the answer in the "Your Answer" box.

Comment: Be glad to but shouldn't you have given me the chance before deleting the answer?

Comment: No, I don’t really see why I should have.  If you can find documented policy and/or other high-rep users that support your position, feel free to bring them to my attention.   Meanwhile, thank you for conforming to the standard practices of [SE].

Comment: Hi madrat. I think Scott's comment would have been more constructive if it added that all edits can be viewed, by clicking where it says ["edited yesterday"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/531168/revisions).  This means the deleted content was/is still available for you to copy. Since you have some reputation already, I believe it is possible for you to write questions about site policies on https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com if you like. Given that, I will resist the temptation to debate this further here :-).

Comment: Yes, sourcejedi, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to all apps and start "Tweaks".
2. On the left side of the window, select "Keyboard & Mouse".
3. In the main part of the window, near the bottom, you'll see "Mouse Click Emulation".
4. Change the setting to "Area".